# SQL INSERT is not working with OUTPUT INSERTED statement

Tags: sql, dbeaver, mariadb-10.2

My goal is to insert a new row in a database table and immediately get back the ID of the inserted row. 
I saw some other posts on stackoverflow that suggested to use this command:

`INSERT INTO selecttable (name) OUTPUT INSERTED.ID VALUES ('aName')`

Unfortunately, the execution of this command fails with the following error message:

*You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'OUTPUT INSERTED.ID VALUES ('aName')'*

The execution of the command without the output statement worked well:

`INSERT INTO selecttable (name) VALUES ('aName')`

Do you have an idea, why the command above is not working?

Comment: Does MariaDB support `OUTPUT` in `INSERT` statements?

Comment: @GordonLinoff - maybe they could check the manual for their version of MariaDB for the right syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, I think you use `LAST_INSERT_ID()`:

```
INSERT INTO selecttable (name)
    VALUES ('aName');

SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

This is an imperfect equivalent construct.  For instance, it doesn't work so well with multiple rows.  But it is the MariaDB/MySQL solution to this problem.